# How to make a SVG element equal to a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I would like to know how I could set a variable in javascript equal to an SVG element, if that is possible.

Comment: an existing element? document.getElementById, create an element document.createElementNS or something else?

Answer (score 0):

This function will return one, you can just assign it to whatever variable

```
 var svgElementFromString = function(str) {
    var div = document.createElement('DIV');
    div.innerHTML = str;
    var svg = div.querySelector('svg');
    if (!svg) { console.log('No SVG found in loaded contents'); return; }
    else return svg;
  }
```

...

```
var mySvg = svgElementFromString('<svg height=100% width=100% viewbox="0 0 30 30">  <rect width=30 height=30 style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" /></svg>');
```

But if you already have an existing one in your document, all you have to do is query for it and assign it to a variable. No need to parse it via string.